# Specific task from class. I am not asking for answer but an explanation of the main objective

Tags: java, bluej

I am a very beginner of Java and hope to learn more about this language. I know it take practice and I hope to explore this question to the best of my abilities however I need to understand the question more. I have done some of my  code however can not post it as others in my class will be able to see it and copy the code.

here are the questions::

---

Suppose you are designing a program for an automated teller machine. The ATM generates transactions that are sent to the banks central computer for processing.

In this assignment, you will create two classes, “Account” and “Transaction”. An Account object should have a unique account number, which can be represented by an integer, and a balance. Initially the balance is zero. A Transaction object should have an amount being transacted and a reference to the Account class associated with the transaction.

Here is an example of the two classes being invoked:

```
/**
 * This class contains a main method that calls methods in the classes you will write.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class RunTransactions
{
    static void main()
    {
       // Create two new accounts with the given account numbers
       Account fred = new Account(1234);
       Account jim = new Account(6778);

       // Provide accessor methods for account information.
       int accountNumber = fred.getAccountNumber();
       float balance = fred.getBalance();

       // Transactions consist of an account reference and an amount
       Transaction t1 = new Transaction(fred, 20);
       Transaction t2 = new Transaction(jim, 10);
       Transaction t3 = new Transaction(jim, -20);

       // Transactions must contain a "process" method that is called to
       //  actually perform the transaction.
       // A transaction should not be allowed if it results in a negative balance.
       t1.process();
       t2.process();
       t3.process();

       // Print out a report of the account balance.
       // The format should be like this: Account 6778 has balance $20.0
       fred.report();
       jim.report();
    }
}
```

Download this file. It contains a BlueJ project with just the RunTransactions class. You must create your own Account and Transaction classes. You can create whatever fields and methods you think appropriate but you must provide methods that can be called exactly as above.

The report method should print out a simple message giving the account number and balance. The format should be

```
   Account <account number> has balance $<account balance>
```

For example, the output of the reports from the above sample code should be:

```
   Account 1234 has balance $20.0
   Account 6778 has balance $10.0
```

You will learn about main methods and the static qualifier in later lectures. For now, you only need to know that when you right click on the RunTransactions class, you will see an item in the menu void main(). Clicking on this will run the main method, which will call your code.

You may change the main method to test your code with different combinations of accounts and transactions. Only remember that you must use exactly the same names of classes and methods and the types of arguments are return values must be identical.

When you submit your assignment, we test your code with different main methods.

Comment: So what was your question?

Answer (score 0):

they are asking you to write the two classes - **Account** and **Transaction**, so that when the code in the provided RunTransactions executes (the main method is run), the application will produce the expected output. Good luck!